# How to add scroll background effect to multiple elements with different settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this demo http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/527/Animated-background-image-with-jQuery

This code is for one background only. I want to add multiple background with different direction and speed.

```
 var scrollSpeed = 70;
 var step = 1;
 var current = 0;
 var imageWidth = 2247;
 var headerWidth = 800;  

 var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

 function scrollBg(){
  current -= step;
  if (current == restartPosition){
   current = 0;
  }

  $('#header').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
 }

 var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

Currently it has settings for

```
  $('#header').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
```

In a website I want to use this effect on `#footer` or `#content` background also. but with different speed and direction.

**And is there any better and more optimized jquery method to achieve same effect?**

And can we get same effect using CSS 3, without javascript?

Comment: Don't use a string as the first parameter of `setInterval` just pass the function, e.g `setInterval(scrollBg, scrollSpeed)` passing a string will call `eval` in the background, which is evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just saw the OP's answer, but decided to post anyway:

I've created a jQuery plugin to do this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scrollingBackground = function(options) {
        // settings and defaults.
        var settings = options || {};
        var speed = settings.speed || 1;
        var step = settings.step || 1;
        var direction = settings.direction || 'rtl';
        var animStep;

        // build up a string to pass to animate:
        if (direction === 'rtl') {
            animStep = "-=" + step + "px";
        }
        else if (direction === 'ltr') {
            animStep = '+=' + step + "px";
        }

        var element = this;

        // perform the animation forever:
        var animate = function() {
            element.animate({
                backgroundPosition: animStep + " 0px"
            }, speed, animate);           
        };
        animate();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$("#header").scrollingBackground({
    speed: 50,
    step: 50,
    direction: 'ltr'
});
```

This is pretty basic, and assumes that you're background-repeat is 'repeat-x' on the element you call it on.  This way, there's no need to reset the background position every so often.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/xmtpr/

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Thanks for the answer and jsFiddle link. What is the difference between your solution compate to link which i found?

Comment: @Jitendra: I've just visited the link you posted.  I guess the only difference is that I'm using jQuery animate and not setInterval.  The plugin you posted looks a little more robust with more options and whatnot.  I'm also not using `eval()` anywhere.

Comment: @Jitendra: I'm not sure.  I can do some benchmarking and get back to you.  I suspect the difference will be minimal though; it depends on the implementation of jQuery's animate function.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Have you tested?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: I set up a jsperf here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-bg-animate that leads me to believe my solution is faster.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Thanks very much. Thanks for making this plugin and giving me this answer. I appreciate all of your efforts.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - and thanks again for sharing this useful site with me jspref

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - I'm facing one problem. When I change anything here `backgroundPosition: animStep + " 0px"` ,animation stops. background images are bottom aligned in my case and when i apply your jQuery animation, images come on top and if i change `backgroundPosition: animStep + " 0px 0px"` animation stops.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: How are you bottom-aligning your images? `backgroundPosition` expects `backgroundPosition: Xpx Ypx`.

Comment: `background-position {0 bottom}`

Comment: @Jitendra: You could try `backgroundPosition: animStep + " bottom"` (untested).

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Did you checked in IE? Your example link is not working in IE 8 and 7 :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655405/jquery-example-in-jsfiddle-working-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie8-7

Answer (score 0):

I could work out the following solution. Am not sure if it is efficient. Will wait for anyone to comment or provide a better option.
Till then...:

```
var scrollSpeed = 70;
 var step = 1;
 var current = 0;
 var images = 
 [
    {
    imageWidth:2247,
    imagePath:"images/image1"
    },
    {
    imageWidth:1200,
    imagePath:"images/image2"
    }
 ]
 var headerWidth = 800;  
 var imageRotateCount = 0;
 var imagesLength = images.length;

 $('#header').css("background-image", images[0].imagePath);

 function scrollBg(){
    var curIndex = imageRotateCount%imagesLength;
    var curImage = images[curIndex];
  current -= step;

    var restartPosition = -(curImage.imageWidth - headerWidth);
  if (current == restartPosition){
   current = 0;
     imageRotateCount++;
     curIndex = imageRotateCount%imagesLength;
     curImage = images[curIndex];
     $('#header').css("background-image", curImage.imagePath);
  }

  $('#header').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
 }

 var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```