# jQuery example (in jsfiddle) working in firefox but not in IE8, 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, cross-browser

Why this example not working in IE http://jsfiddle.net/8RZVt/

I'm getting this error in IE8.

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 156
Char: 295
Code: 0
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
```

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710756/ie8-var-w-window-open-message-invalid-argument

Answer (score 7):

According to jQuery, this is because, as stated on the `animate` documentation page:

> All animated properties should be a
>   **single numeric value** (except as noted
>   below); properties that are
>   non-numeric cannot be animated using
>   basic jQuery functionality....

So, in fact, in Firefox you are using undefined behavior.  The correct thing to do would be to animate on backgroundPositionX, however Firefox does not support this.

There is, however, a jQuery plugin that does what you want:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

**Update**

On closer inspection, the plugin does not support `+=` or `-=` formats.

I hacked it into this example:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/CxqSs/</strike>  (See new example at bottom.)

Could definitely use some cleanup, and should probably be added to that plug-in, but it works in both browsers and doesn't rely on undefined behavior.

BTW, I don't know if it's worth noting, but if you leave this animation running a long time, it will eventually overflow the value and break.  This could be overcome by animating the full length of the background image and then resetting the offset to 0px in the callback before the next animate.  This would also avoid needing the `+=` format.

**Also**,

It should be noted that `speed: 1, step: 1` and `speed: 50, step: 50` are equivalent.

The reason they look different speeds is because

1. There is more overhead in a speed of 1 (which is really a millisecond duration) because animate gets called more often.
2. The default easing is "swing", meaning that the animation speeds up and slows down slightly throughout it's course, meaning that the overall speed is affected a bit.  You should change the easing to "linear" for your scrolling case:

   ```
   var animate = function() {
       element.animate({
           ...
       }, speed, "linear", animate);            
   };
   ```

**This means** that you could use the backgroundPosition-Effect plugin, without the '+=', by setting your step to 2247 (the width of the image), like I stated above.

And that **finally** brings us to... wait for it...

http://jsfiddle.net/zyQj3/20/

Cross-platform, non-kludgy, non-overflowing, correctly easing, extra parameter-lacking, solution.

Comment: My examples work in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, and they work correctly.

Comment: LOL, I didn't have a copy of IE7 to use, but after getting one, after much debugging, the problem is unrelated.  Remove the commas after `step: 2247,` and `step: -2247,`.  That's it.  http://jsfiddle.net/Rn3sc/3/

Answer (score 4):

The script fails at this point because you are passing an invalid CSS value:

```
element.animate({
          backgroundPosition: animStep + " 0px" /* evaluates to "+=50px 0px" */
 }, speed, animate);
```

Comment: it's `" 0px"` with **space** do you actually knows what this script do?

Comment: Thanks, fixed the space typo.  It is still invalid CSS: "+=50px 0px".

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: I don't think so, this is the same as your code! anyway I'm researching what could be the issue

Comment: It is his code, I cut and pasted the part of his code that was causing the IE error....

Comment: I think you might have to use eval(animStep + "0px") here to get it working, or something along that line. It seems IE evaluates just the 'backgroundPosition: animStep' part so you have to force it.

Answer (score 2):

OK here  we go again :D

http://jsfiddle.net/c7rKV/1/

Again identical to original however again just animating backgroundPositionX when in IE.

Apologies on not actually looking at FF/Chrome last time.

Additionally: this of course is not very graceful and Adam Prax is absolutely correct on what the problem is.  I just wanted to post a solution to it.

Comment: Works in IE bah, my apologies. I should test before posting.

Comment: Totally but why when I'm just coming back with the same identical answer (albeit one that works) in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source code of jQuery, you will see it uses [this regexp](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L5) to parse the parameter (which in your case is `+=50px 0px`). So it will see it as `+=` (increase) `50` (to fifty) `px 0px` (unit, append after the number). When trying to read the current value, [jQuery uses  parseFloat](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L334), which just grabs the number at the start of the string. So it works perfectly, even if a multi-dimensional property is probably not what the jQuery programmers had in mind.

Except that IE8 does not support getting the current value of `background-position`. There is `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` but no `background-position`. Duh. So your best bet is checking the browser type, and animating either `background-position` or `background-position-x` depending on that: http://jsfiddle.net/22UWW/

(There is actually a [jQuery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7681) about this, with a [more elegant solution](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js).)

Comment: your solution is working fine, but in my case, background images's height is shorten than `div` and I need images at bottom of the `div` , in IE it's fine, images coming at bottom but in firefox they are going to top

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: You could try replacing 0px with 100%, or just use an inner div with the exact same size as the image.