# jQuery animation callback is not been excecuted in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have the following animation :

```
           $(this).animate({
              marginLeft: '-25%',
              width: "50%",
              minWidth: '400px',
              maxWidth: '700px',
              padding: 0,
              minHeight: "580px",
              height: 'auto',
              borderRadius: 0
            }, 1000, function () {
              alert("I'm not being displayed!!");
              $(this).addClass('completed');
            });
```

All seems ok, but the callback is not been called in IE7 or 8. Why would this be? 
I removed the last comma after borderRadius which fixed the original animation problem, but now this is the new issue. 
Can anyone  help?

EDIT:

The final alert with the punctuation error is not actually in the code, I have only placed it there to avoid people pointing out that the addClass part may have been the problem!

Comment: Check the order of quotes in the callback - those mismatched single quotes are causing you issues in the alert.

Comment: Please read the edit above. Apologies for my attention to detail!

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle so that we can see this in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested I found out what the problem was. Apparently IE 7 and 8 had problems dealing with `height: 'auto'` within the animate function, which was causing it to not fire off the callback.

I decided to use trial and error to comment out certain properties until I found the culprit after reading an answer on this question - [jQuery example (in jsfiddle) working in firefox but not in IE8, 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655405/jquery-example-in-jsfiddle-working-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie8-7) - by [Jeff B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179216/jeff-b)

Answer (score 4):

Add an escape in the "I ' m "

```
  $(this).animate({
                      marginLeft: '-25%',
                      width: "50%",
                      minWidth: '400px',
                      maxWidth: '700px',
                      padding: 0,
                      minHeight: "580px",
                      height: 'auto',
                      borderRadius: 0
                    }, 1000, function () {
                      alert('I\'m not being displayed!!'); // needed an escape
                      $(this).addClass('completed');
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
$(this).animate({
          marginLeft: '-25%',
          width: "50%",
          minWidth: '400px',
          maxWidth: '700px',
          padding: 0,
          minHeight: "580px",
          height: 'auto',
          borderRadius: 0
        }, 1000).promise().done(function(){
          alert("I'm not being displayed!!"); // <---use double quotes or escape them
          $(this).addClass('completed');
        });
```